# The range of $\int_M \kappa_g ds$ where $g$ varies in all possible real analytic metrics on $M$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature, real-analytic-structures

Let $M$ be a real analytic open surface(A non compact 2 dimensional manifold without boundary).

For every  number $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$, is there a real analytic Riemannian metric on $M$ with
$$\int_M \kappa ds=\lambda$$

Comment: If $g$ is a metric with curvature $\kappa$ then, for $r>0$ real, $r\cdot g$ has curvature $r^{-2} \cdot \kappa$, right? So it has integral $\lambda/r^2$

Comment: @Qfwfq  Yes so what about zero integral?

Comment: @Qfwfq  I was thinking to this since since I realized the Pfaffian is n-homogeneous

Comment: @Qfwfq  and what about $\pm$ sign?

Comment: I think my comment implies that, given a $\lambda\neq 0$, every other $\lambda'$ with the same sign is reachable by rescaling $g$.

Comment: @Qfwfq  Yes I get it. So we should modify the question for $\lambda \in \{-1,0,1\}$

Comment: (maybe I got the powers of $r$ wrong now, but the idea should stand)

Comment: @Qfwfq The rescalling you pointed out to effects on integrant "ds" too. otherwise we arrive at the point that  the"Gauss Bonne theorem" is not true.

Comment: @Ali Taghavi indeed dVol will scale precisely so as to cancel this (as it must for GB theorem to be true)

Comment: @EBz  Yes indeed.

Comment: @Ali Taghavi: Maybe, strangely, if I saw "dVol" written instead of "ds" I wouldn't have overseen that :) , but you're totally right. I think also the following heuristic leads to cancellation. Curvature is the reciprocal of curvature radii, each of which scales as lenght $\int \sqrt{g(\gamma'(t),\gamma'(t))}dt$, $\rho_1\mapsto r^{1/2} \cdot \rho_1$ when $g\mapsto r\cdot g$ (same for $\rho_2$), so $\kappa \mapsto r^{-1} \kappa$. The volume form scales as $\sqrt{\det(g_{ij})}$ so $dVol \mapsto r \cdot dVol $. So this results in $\kappa dVol \mapsto \kappa dVol$

Comment: So, when you inflate a surface curvature becomes "less dense" but "there's totally the same amount of it". This is an intuition about curvature (possibly obvious to many) that I didn't have before your question.